# Else if statement inside for each loop - C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a foreach loop like this where I want the else condition to output: "unit not found" if the quad.ID == searchForQuadcopters isn't found but I get this string value output even when the value is found.

```
foreach (var quad in allQuadcopters)
{
    if (quad.ID == searchForQuadcopter)
    {
        WriteLine("Value found.");
        // write here all the information you want to display.
        WriteLine($"ID: {quad.ID}");
        WriteLine($"Capacity (kg): {quad.capacityKg}");
        WriteLine($"Reach (km): {quad.reachKm}");
        WriteLine($"Transponder ID: {quad.transponderID}");
        quad.vehicleDeliveryForm();
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("Unit not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using a loop (i.e., checking multiple elements), how do you know that that message is for an element that meets the `if` condition, and not one that doesn't? Did you do anything to verify that?

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes I've tested, in the console the output is either empty if there is no value or if there is a value it outputs the value but also outputs "Unit not found" even when there is a value

Comment: It's a loop so it will display `value found` and `value not found` message multiple times based on individual `quad.ID`

Comment: Your approach is close but not quite there.  You are going to evaluate the if/else statement for every quad in allQuadcopters, and it will either match or not, and output the text accordingly.  What you need to do is check all quads until you find a match, at which point you will output the details.  Only if you find no matches will you output "Unit not found", and that will have to happen outside of the loop.  Have a think - I'm sure you'll get it.

Comment: have you considered using LINQ instead? `var quad = allQuadcopters.Where(q=>q.ID == searchforQuadcopter).SingleOrDefault()` will give you either the object in question, or `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the else condition to output: "unit not found" if the quad.ID == searchForQuadcopters isn't found

Then you don't want this loop. Your code loops over all items, and if `allQuadcopters` contains Ids 1, 2 and 3 and you're looking for 2, it will print "Unit not found" for Ids 1 and 3. You could `break;` out of the loop in your `if()`, but then the `else` will still be hit for 1.

You want to leverage Linq here:

```
var quad = allQuadcopters.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == searchForQuadcopters);

if (quad == null)
{
    WriteLine("Unit not found");
}
else
{
    WriteLine("Value found.");
    // write here all the information you want to display.
    WriteLine($"ID: {quad.ID}");
}
```

Comment: "Then you don't want this loop" -> careful, someone might interpret that as LINQ magically not using loops :)

Comment: Thank you guys for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You won't know if the value isn't found unless you iterate over the ENTIRE list first and don't encounter it.

Create a boolean flag to track whether the value was found or not:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (var quad in allQuadcopters)
{
    if (quad.ID == searchForQuadcopter)
    {
        found = true;
        WriteLine("Value found.");
        // write here all the information you want to display.
        WriteLine($"ID: {quad.ID}");
        WriteLine($"Capacity (kg): {quad.capacityKg}");
        WriteLine($"Reach (km): {quad.reachKm}");
        WriteLine($"Transponder ID: {quad.transponderID}");
        quad.vehicleDeliveryForm();
        break; // if you don't want to iterate over the rest
    }
}
if (!found) {
  WriteLine("Unit not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help :)